# How do you declare instance of the class in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Let's imagine I have Fraction class. So, the correct way to create instance of it is:

```
Fraction *myFraction;
or
myFraction = Fraction;
or
myFraction = [Fraction new];
```

or something else?

In the book i'm studying the correct one is first, but it looks unreasonable to me. Why do we have to create a pointer for it? Why don't we make the real instance?

That first expression means - give me a pointer to the new instance of Fraction class, doesn't it?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first declares a variable named `myFraction` of type `Fraction *`, but doesn't create anything, nor initialize `myFraction`. The second isn't valid. The third creates a new `Fraction` and assigns it to a previously declared variable named `myFraction`. Often in Objective-C, you'll declare and initialize a variable in a single statement:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
```

As for whether to use `new` or `alloc` followed by `init`, it's largely a matter of taste.

Variables for storing objects are pointers in part because Objective-C inherited C's [call-by-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) semantics. When one variable is assigned to another (such as when passing it to a function), the value will be copied. At best, this is inefficient for immutable objects. At worst, it leads to incorrect behavior. Pointers are a way around call-by-value and the copy-on-assign semantics: the value of a variable with pointer type is just the pointer. It can be copied without touching the target object. The cost for this is you need some form of [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 3):

It would be a good idea to read Kernihan and Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" so you can get an idea about how variables are declared.

There are two modes of allocation in C and Obj-C and C++: **manual** and **automatic**.

Integers and floats and characters and such are generally automatically declared. They are created when the declaration passes (i.e. **int i**), and deleted when the scope they were created in goes away, i.e. when you exit the block in which they were declared. They're called **automatics**. (it's also possible to declare them "static" but for the purposes of this discussion regarding allocation, these are the same)

Objects are too complicated to pass around to functions, as function parameters are "pass by value", meaning that the parameter gets a copy of the value being passed in, instead of the variable itself. It'd take a huge amount of time to copy a whole object all the time.

For this reason, you want to just tell the various functions where they can find the object. Instead of handing off a copy of the object, you hand off a copy of the address of the object. The address is stored in an automatic with a type of **pointer**. (This is really just an integer, but it's size is dictated by the hardware and OS, so it needs to be a special type.)

The declaration **Fraction *myFraction;** means "myFraction is a pointer, and just so you know, it's going to point to a Fraction later."

This will automatically allocate *the pointer*, but not the whole Fraction. For that to happen, you must call **alloc** and **init**.

The big reason why you have this two step process is that since we typically want objects to stick around for a while, we don't want the system automatically killing them at the end of a function. We need them to persist. We create places to hang the object in our functions, but those hangers go away when they aren't needed. We don't want them taking the object with them.

Ultimately, you might make declarations like this:

```
Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] initWithNumerator: 2 Denominator: 3];
```

which says: "Make me a Fraction, and set it to be 2/3, and then put the address of that Fraction into 'myFraction'."

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have to create a pointer for it? Why don't we make the real instance?

In Objective-C, every object is pointer type. So, you need to use either `new` or `alloc/init`.

```
Fraction *myFraction = [ Fraction new ] ;
```

or

```
Fraction *myFraction = [ [Fraction alloc] init ] ;
```

And `myFraction` needs to be released.

> That first expression means - give me a pointer to the new instance of Fraction class, doesn't it?

No, you are just declaring a pointer of type `Fraction`. And the second statement is not even valid.